# Mutliple forms on a page with each one being able to submit

Tags: javascript, forms

How is it possible to have multiple forms on a page with each one being able to submit itself.
When i have it set up like this, the first forms submits, but the 2nd does not work. Any suggestions on how to make it work? (I will have many forms like this on 1 page)

thanks

```
<form action="/order-form2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="phoneType" value="iPhone 2g - 4GB//ATT">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="75">
<div class="prodSize"><a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">4 GB</a></div> 
</form>

   <form  action="/order-form2.php">
<input type="hidden" name="phone" value="iPhone 2g - 8GB//ATT">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="25">
<div class="prodSize"><a href="#" onclick="document.forms[1].submit();">8 GB</a></div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for 2nd form it will work. as default method is set to get if it has no method.

```
<form action="/order-form2.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

first form is set method to post, second has not, if you're catching with POST then it's empty, set the method to post or catch with GET, if it's not set method, default is GET

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following

```
<form name='form1' id='form1' method='POST' action='/order-form1.php'>
    <a href="#" onclick='return document.forms.form1.submit();'>4 GB</a>
</form>
```

Note the id and name attributes assigned to form, use that in javascript